# SailsJS + Rotational direction coordinates calculation issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm creating a small game to learn how NodeJS & Sails work (and by extension Waterline, Socket.io, Express, and all their components).

I'm using websockets to make the **server** calculate the coordinates. Everything is handled server-side.
The client only receives serialized data in order to redraw the whole canvas.

For debugging purposes, I decided not to redraw but simply "draw" (leaving the old canvas visible) to show you the result.

See below for situation, issue and code.

### The issue

I'm having trouble when **calculating coordinates**.

What I need is a simple **forward/backwards** system, and when pressing `left` or `right` keys, change the direction angle so the character can move in the canvas.

Kinda like the good'ol *Asteroids* retro games.

The issue is the following:

[image]

The drawn loops you see shouldn't exist. In fact, they should be **circles**. I drew this by simply pressing either `up` or `down` key, combined with one of `left` or `right` keys.

I think there is an issue in the calculation system...

This shouldn't be a performance issue because each tick occurs at the same interval, so even if it was a performance issue, it should only be related to delay when redrawing the canvas, not such an offset in coordinates calculation...

Any idea ?

#### Info about code api

- `moves` contains a javascript object like this:
  `{ left:false, right: false, up: false, down:  false }`
  It is used to check whether the user is "pressing" associated arrow keys.
  It is updated each time there is a `keyUp` or `keyDown` event client-side.
- `user.pick` contains the "physical object" to be rendered in the canvas, which contain `x`, `y` coordinates, and information about movement speed and rotation speed.

#### Here's the code that handles the coordinates calculation.

```js
// Change angle if "left" or "right" is pushed
if (moves.left || moves.right) {
    // let PI2 = 2 * PI;
    let angle = user.pick.angle;

    if (moves.left) {
        angle += user.pick.angleSpeed;
    } else if (moves.right) {
        angle -= user.pick.angleSpeed;
    }

    // Use this to avoid having huge integers to manage
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle = 360 - angle;
    }
    if (angle > 360) {
        angle = angle - 360;
    }

    user.pick.angle = parseInt(angle);
}

// Up and down allow us to move either forwards or backwards.
if (moves.up || moves.down) {

    let moveRatio = moves.up ? 1 : -1;

    let angleRadians = user.pick.angle * (PI / 180);
    let x = user.pick.x + moveRatio * user.pick.speed * Math.sin(angleRadians);
    let y = user.pick.y + moveRatio * user.pick.speed * Math.cos(angleRadians);

    // Avoids collisions with canvas walls
    if (x > 0 && x < user.map.width) {
        user.pick.x = parseInt(x);
    }
    if (y > 0 && y < user.map.height) {
        user.pick.y = parseInt(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: At a glance, there's a bug in how you handle negative angles — it should be `angle + 360` not `360 - angle`. For example, let angle be -30. Our expected output is +330. This code gives us 360 - (-30) = 390, then the next `if` triggers and we get 390 - 360 = 30, so our angle has been inverted. I don't think this is the whole cause of the error you observe, but it's low-hanging fruit to fix.

Comment: You're totally right, I couldn't figure out why there was this bug. I fixed this by using a modulo instead, which is much simpler (but still it drives me crazy as I'm not an expert mathematician). You can see this in my big and exhaustive answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having received help in private, let me post the answer here (and thanks a lot for the ones that helped me on Twitter :) )

### First change: angle udpate

A friend of mine who is a mathematician told me that the `angle` security could be handled with a simple modulo.

He gave me the hint to remove this code:

```
if (angle < 0) {
    angle = 360 - angle;
}
if (angle > 360) {
    angle = angle - 360;
}
```

And instead, replace it with this code:

```
if (angle <= 0 || angle >= 360) {
    angle %= 360;
}
```

And it works very well!

Because the issue with the first code was that when the `angle < 0`, it oscillated between 0 and `-speed` (meaning `-10` in my case), so the pointer was moving down and not rotating.

### Second change (and the most important): values rounding

The same friend, and also @voidqk on Twitter, told me to `stop rounding values`.

This is a **great** advice because **I was not rounding values at all**. I was **parsing them to int**.

Meaning I had this:

```
console.info(
    parseInt(1.2), // 1
    parseInt(1.6), // 1
    parseInt(-1.2), // -1
    parseInt(-1.6) // -1
);
```

This was **totally incorrect**.

I replaced everything with `Math.round()` and now it rounds values in a proper way:

```
console.info(
    Math.round(1.2), // 1
    Math.round(1.6), // 2
    Math.round(-1.2), // -1
    Math.round(-1.6) // -2
);
```

The `parseInt()` method introduced an incorrect offset in negative coordinates, whereas `Math.round()` does the job very well and now when I move my pointer and push the `left` arrow key, I can now draw circles :D

[image: Proper circles]